# Assigning datetime after groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a climatology i.e. averaging like this on a dataframe with multiple years of daily data and datetime as index:

```
df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day]).mean()
```

Once I do the groupby, the datetime index vanishes. That makes sense since there is no unique datetime for each row after the groupby.

Is there a way I can reintroduce a datetime after the groupby is done, by artificially assigning a year?

-- EDIT dataframe:

```
datetime    val1    val2
1/1/2000    74.25769    5.813470958
1/2/2000    74.25769    5.813470958
1/3/2000    74.25769    5.813470958
1/4/2000    74.25769    5.813470958
1/5/2000    76.67728083 5.813470958
1/6/2000    76.67728083 5.813470958
1/7/2000    76.67728083 5.813470958
1/4/2001    76.67728083 5.813470958
1/5/2001    77.30620917 12.3357252
1/6/2001    77.30620917 12.3357252
1/7/2001    77.30620917 12.3357252
1/8/2001    77.30620917 12.3357252
1/9/2001    77.30620917 12.3357252
1/10/2001   77.30620917 12.3357252
```

Comment: IIUC you could do it with groupping your `df` with `reset_index` and then `set_index` with from grouped

Comment: thanks @AntonProtopopov, if you can add it as answer, I can test and accept

Comment: Could you show your `df`? may be with something like `df.head(10)`?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov, added sample dataframe

Comment: Hmm, `mean` with `dtype`  `datetime64[ns]` gives me the error: `TypeError: reduction operation 'mean' not allowed for this dtype`. So after I'm doing that: `df1 = df.reset_index(); df1.groupby([df1.datetime.dt.month, df1.datetime.dt.day]).mean()`    `datetime` column is dissapeared..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you lost `year` information, but you can set it after [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with custom `year` with `months` and `days` from `index`:

```
import datetime

df = df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day]).mean()
print df
           val1       val2
1 1   74.257690   5.813471
  2   74.257690   5.813471
  3   74.257690   5.813471
  4   75.467485   5.813471
  5   76.991745   9.074598
  6   76.991745   9.074598
  7   76.991745   9.074598
  8   77.306209  12.335725
  9   77.306209  12.335725
  10  77.306209  12.335725

df['Date'] = df.index.map(lambda x: datetime.date(2000, x[0], x[1]))
print df.set_index('Date')
                 val1       val2
Date                            
2000-01-01  74.257690   5.813471
2000-01-02  74.257690   5.813471
2000-01-03  74.257690   5.813471
2000-01-04  75.467485   5.813471
2000-01-05  76.991745   9.074598
2000-01-06  76.991745   9.074598
2000-01-07  76.991745   9.074598
2000-01-08  77.306209  12.335725
2000-01-09  77.306209  12.335725
2000-01-10  77.306209  12.335725
```